# Updating the original reference to an object that was returned from a linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to do something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Submit(Person UpdatedPerson)
{
    //Find the original Person that the model was bound against
    //Update the collection's reference to reflect the changes
    //from the posted model version
    Person original = PersonCollection
                        .SingleOrDefault(p=>p.Id == UpdatedPerson.Id);
    if(original!=null)
    {
        //update the value from PersonCollection
        //doesn't work, of course
        original = UpdatedPerson;
    }
}
```

I'm currently doing this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Submit(Person UpdatedPerson)
{
    //Find the index into PersonCollection for the original 
    //model bound object, use the index to directly mutate the 
    //PersonCollection collection
    int refIndex = -1;
    for(int i=0;i<PersonCollection.Length;i++)
    {
        if(PersonCollection[i].Id == UpdatedPerson.Id)
        {
            refIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(refIndex >= 0)
    {
        PersonCollection[refIndex] = UpdatedPerson;
    }
}
```

It feels like I'm missing something simple here, it shouldn't be so much trouble to accomplish what I'm after.

What is the best practice way to do this sort of stuff?

Comment: How is `PersonCollection` indexed? What type is it?

Comment: @Rikon Person is just an example, the model binding works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, you make a variable declaration:

```
Person original;
```

That `original` variable is a reference.

Then you assign it to some item in your list

Then later you make a call like this:

```
original = UpdatedPerson;
```

In this call, you're updating the variable reference, not anything from the collection.

What you might want to do is something like this (Presuming Person is a class, not a struct):

```
original.UpdateValuesToMatch(UpdatedPerson);
```

but you'd have to create such a method on the person object.

Or in your second method, you could simplify from:

```
    if(PersonCollection[i].Id == UpdatedPerson.Id)
    {
        refIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
if(refIndex >= 0)
{
    PersonCollection[refIndex] = UpdatedPerson;
}
```

to

```
    if(PersonCollection[i].Id == UpdatedPerson.Id)
    {
        PersonCollection[i] = UpdatedPerson;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, I do understand why it doesn't work, I am looking for an easier maybe more standard method with the same intent as that, that is not as... well, weird i guess, as the second method.

Comment: @asawyer Well, I did provide a workaround. I'll give you another.

Comment: Per Edit - That's a good point, and makes the intent alot more clear.  That combined with an extension verson of FindIndex looks like might be my best bet.

Comment: @asawyer I don't think mixing my response with find index is a good idea. I think it's kinda one or the other. Find index and update based on that index, or go through the loop, and update when the time is right.

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
original = UpdatedPerson;
```

you are just assigning the reference to `original`, thus `original` now points to the same object that `UpdatedPerson` points to. and that is why you are losing the reference value for the object that you have retrieved from the collection.

Try assigning the individual fields instead.

Comment: Sure, I understand why it doesn't work. I was hoping to avoid the trouble of updating all the properties though, as there are quite a few.

Comment: @asawyer - Is PersonCollection a database table?

Comment: It just IList<Person> (Person btw is just an example, the real code deals with insurance claimants)

Answer (score 1):

#### Description

You can use `FindIndex`

#### Sample

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Submit(Person UpdatedPerson)
{
    //Find the index into PersonCollection for the original 
    //model bound object, use the index to directly mutate the 
    //PersonCollection collection
    int refIndex = PersonCollection.FindIndex(x => x.Id == UpdatedPerson.Id);
    if (refIndex != -1)
         PersonCollection[refIndex] = UpdatedPerson;
}
```

#### More Information

- [List.FindIndex Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k601hd9.aspx)

Comment: I have an IList<T> acutally which doesn't have this method. It would be a simple matter to add my own extension for it though. I like this idea.

Comment: `IList<T>` is the interface. What class you use the implements `IList<T>`?

Comment: The concrete implementation is a normal List<T>, but that is an implementation detail. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8717782/426894

Comment: `List<T>` has the method `FindIndex` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx