# Assigning to an IList< > or a List< >?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why use IList or List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717582/why-use-ilist-or-list)

I have the following:

```
public class CityViewModel
{
    public CityViewModel() {     
        Details = Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select(x => new City.Detail()).ToList(); 
    }
    public string Topic { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }
    public IList<City.Detail> Details { get; set; }
}
```

The suggestion as a way to create Details was given to me. What I am unsure about is why the following line is declared as an IList:

```
public IList<City.Detail> Details { get; set; }
```

Would it not be more correct to declare this as:

```
public List<City.Detail> Details { get; set; }
```

Can someone explain the difference to me.

Comment: IList is preferable for mocking in tests

Comment: But when I have IList in there then the following failed in another part of code: vm.Details.RemoveAll(x => x.Text.TextWithHtml == null);  I found to get this to work I had to add vm.Details.ToList(); to make it into a list again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an interface rather than the class is definitely the right way to go, both for information hiding and testability reasons. I would even go further, and suggest using `ICollection<T>` instead of `IList<T>` if you can: this would give you even more flexibility as far as choosing an alternative implementation goes, while letting your users perform mostly the same operations.

Moreover, I would probably not use an automatic assignable property for it: I'd return a read-only version, and provided separate methods for manipulating the list on my own class.

Here is what I would do:

```
public class CityViewModel {
    private readonly List<City.Detail> details;
    public CityViewModel() {
        // Here you assign a List to details
    }
    public ICollection<City.Detail> Details {
        get {
            return details.AsReadOnly();
        }
    }
}
```

This hides implementation of the list from users, does not let them modify the list behind your back, and does not even tell them that you're using a `List`. If you would decide to use, say, a `HashSet` at some later date, you'd be able to swap it in without a fear of breaking something in the code that uses your class.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you mean when you say use ICollection. I realize there's probably a lot of information out there but for this case what kind of additional functionality would it add.  If I create as an IList then is there any reason for me to have ToList() when I create the initial list?

Comment: @SamanthaJ `ICollection` is a base interface of `IList` and many other collections in .NET. It lets you enumerate the container, and provides the count of items inside it. In most cases, this is all that is needed.

Comment: What I need is some additional functionality such as the ability to empty the list when some elements are null. I was using .RemoveAll. I'm not sure if this is available with ICollection.

Comment: @SamanthaJ Please see the edit: now you have a field called `details` of type `List<T>`, you can do whatever you want to it, including `RemoveAll`. Users of your class, on the other hand, should not be able to call `RemoveAll` on the list of details provided to them: your class owns it, modifications behind the back are not good. If you want to give them functionality like that, you should add a method called `RemoveAllDetails()` and call `details.RemoveAll()` internally.

Answer (score 2):

`IList<T>` is an interface. `List<T>` is a concrete type.

If you want to be telling the user less about your internal implementations (and usually that is something you want to avoid), then you should use `IList<T>` - as you're then free to switch to anything that implements that interface... Which may be an adapter or wrapper of some kind - or a mock for testing.

I'd also consider whether you really need to return a list style object or whether using `IEnumerable<T>` may better suit your needs (if you're just iterating through that list). You'd only need the list if you needed length and direct indexing I think - and even then creating a list from an `IEnumerable<T>` is easy.

Comment: If I assign to an IList<T> do I not lose functionality. I notice later I was not able to use the .RemoveAll until I again converted it back to a List.

Comment: IMO this is a good thing. This is because you expose less of your internals when you return the `IList<T>` than the `List<T>`. If you want callers to be able to mess with your internals then you'll need to give a `List<T>`. However what I'd do in this case is add a 'RemoveAll` member function to the  `CityViewModel` and let it do the clearing for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public IEnumerable<City.Detail> Details { get; private set; }
```

This is probably what you want to START from as an interface for your class.  Expose the minimum necessary capabilities and don't allow external classes to modify the members OR the collection.

Only expose additional functionality (IList) if you need it and only expose a setter if you absolutely need it.

Answer (score 1):

My view on this is that returning IList enables the callers of your method to be agnostic of the underlying implementation. Meaning if you change your implementation inside your method to another collection that also implements IList, you don't have to update any of the callers. Whereas if you return a concrete List, all callers have to be updated if you make a change to the underlying collection type.

Comment: On the flip side, one downside to IList is that it exposes less functionality, so you will be calling .ToList() in cases where you need access to List specific functions.

Comment: Yeah this is the problem that I had noticed. That made me wonder why the person who originally suggested this was saying to use IList.

Comment: Basically if all your callers need to call ToList, then I guess IList becomes a moot point :-)

Answer (score 1):

Basic difference between `IList` and `List` is that IList is an Interface where List is Class. So if you use List you get more built in function to do search or data maniputation.

[List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

[IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx)