# Array, List, or Dictionary for 3 hierarchy classes

Tags: c#, arrays, list, dictionary, nested-class

I had a hard time setting the Title for this question, but here goes:
I have Cars, Race, Ticket.

I need to hold around 1.000.000 Tickets. Each Ticket has 10 races. Each Race has 15 cars.

I would need to iterate through Cars and Races. Tickets will be created on the fly. So i'm thinking Tickets as List<>. But how about Cars / Races? 2d-array, dictionary? Or List within List?

```
myTicket[n][race 1..10][car 1..15].color = "blue"; // ??
```

Any ideas regarding, performance, and beeing easy to work with?
Thanks in advance! Sorry if the question is a bit unclear....

Answer (score 1):

You should create some classes, that's what they are there for.

Class `Ticket` would have a property `Races` of type `List<Race>` (or similar).
Each `Race` would have a property `Cars` of type `List<Car>` (or similar).

Comment: Ah, I only had Ticket and Car, as their own classes. Hm, this sounds like a good idea

Answer (score 1):

Use following data structure

```
public class Car
{
}

public class Race
{
    public IList<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}

public class Ticket
{
    public IList<Race> Races { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Nice, but why IList over List?

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717582/why-use-ilist-or-list)