# Why use "IList" instead of "List"?

Tags: c#, list, oop, interface

Suppose I have this `Student` class:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { set; get; }
    public string StudentName { set; get; }
    public int Age { set; get; }
}
```

I like to create collections of `Student`s using `List`:

```
List<Student> studentList2 = new List<Student>() { 
   new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName = "John", Age = 18 } ,
   new Student() { StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Steve",  Age = 15 } 
};
```

But I've heard that it's usually better to use `IList`:

```
IList<Student> studentList1 = new List<Student>() { 
    new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName = "John", Age = 18 } ,
    new Student() { StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Steve",  Age = 15 }
};
```

I don't understand why people recommend using `IList<Student>` instead of `List<Student>`!

Is it some kind of performance concern? Is it optional and down to personal preference? Or is there another reason?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170/when-to-use-ilist-and-when-to-use-list

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717582/why-use-ilist-or-list

Comment: Specifying the interface instead of the implementation allows you to change the type of list later, and you won't need to go around changing everything down the road.

Comment: can u show me with a example?