# What are the best practices to returns models(DTO) from a method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

While I was going through [Nop Commerce Source Code](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce),they have created [Factories](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/tree/develop/src/Presentation/Nop.Web/Factories) which converts `Domain model in to View models`.

But I see some methods of Factories returns `IList`,some returns `IEnumerable` So I got bit confused why this inconsistency and Why not return IEnumerable.

In the older versions of Nop Commerce,I have seen that they always use to return `IEnumerable<Model>` but now in the latest versions most of the view models are returned in IList.I know with IList its good to work with abstraction instead of concrete type(List) but then **IEnumerable is much better because everything derives from it**.

Now this makes me wonder so as to what data structure to consider while returning model from a method?

**Is it always have to be IEnumerable because everything derives from this interface and most importantly always works with abstraction?**

**Code :**

```
public partial interface ICountryModelFactory
{
    IList<StateProvinceModel> GetStatesByCountryId(string countryId, bool addSelectStateItem);
} 

public partial interface IBlogModelFactory
{ 
   List<BlogPostYearModel> PrepareBlogPostYearModel(); // Now why Concrete List here?
}

public partial interface IProductModelFactory
{
  IEnumerable<ProductOverviewModel> PrepareProductOverviewModels(IEnumerable<Product> products,
            bool preparePriceModel = true, bool preparePictureModel = true,
            int? productThumbPictureSize = null, bool prepareSpecificationAttributes = false,
            bool forceRedirectionAfterAddingToCart = false);

  IList<ProductSpecificationModel> PrepareProductSpecificationModel(Product product);
}
```

I am bit confused here so as to what is the best practices while converting domain model to view model and what data structure is the best to use when returning view model?

Is it always better to return `IEnumerable<MyModel>` from a method like below :

```
public IEnumerable<MyModel> ReturnMyModel(Product product){ }
```

**Note :** This is not a question asking difference between IEnumerable vs IList

**Nop Commerce Version = 4.20**

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8717782/7840778) to (effectively) the same question is worth reading.

Comment: @SteveLand My question is not why to use Ilist or List but whats the best practices when it comes to return Models(DTO) from method and why here in Nop commerce sometimes Ilist of IEnumerable is used?

Comment: Yes, I realise that. I am suggesting that the content in that answer could help you understand their reasons for returning multiple collection types based on the expected usage of the various methods.

Comment: In short the cut and dried "always do X, not Y" answer you are looking for does not exist. Best practice is to use the  collection type best suited to the expected usage of the method - Adam's answer below gives a reasonable explanation of this. The linked answer above is, imo, clearer and more descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

> IEnumerable is much better because everything derives from it.

I don't think that it is the way to think about it. It is neither better nor worse. It is different and serves a different purpose.

**IEnumerable**

- Some resultsets are infinite (or just too big to practically fit into memory). In such cases, yielding the records one by one means that they can be processed without ever having to realise the entire set in memory.
- Some resultsets are held in something that is not actually a list. Maybe it is a queue or a dictionary key or a hashset or something else. Returning as IEnumerable means that the method doesn't need to create a new list object, fill it up with data just to return the client which may never have intended on doing any more than a foreach over it.
- Sometimes you may have the data in a list, but don't want the caller to be modifying that list. If the data is immutable, you can just return your list as an IEnumerable and know they cannot add/remove from your source list

**IList**

- Sometimes the method required you to build the list, so why not give the caller the capability to (efficiently) get the count, access an object by index, add, remove or sort elements without cloning it to yet another a new object

I prefer to think of it in terms of returning the most useful thing that you can provide to the caller. If I return you an IList, you can assign it to an IEnumerable variable, or use it as the value to an IEnumerable parameter of a subsequent method.

So if I have the data in a `List<T>` already, and I am happy for you to mutate that list, then I will return it as an `IList<T>`. But if I have the data in a `Queue<T>`, I am not going to go out of my way to do a `.ToList()` call and return you an IList of it. If you want a List, you can do that yourself, but if you were just iterating it then my `.ToList()` "helpful" call just wasted a whole bunch of clock cycles and RAM.